# Debian - Postfix /var/log/mail.log is blank

Tags: debian, postfix, syslog, rsyslog

Postfix /var/log/mail.log on Debian is blank. I tried `touch /var/log/mail.log`
and then `service rsyslog restart`
but /var/log/mail.log is still blank. What should I do?

Comment: Are other `/var/log/mail*` files present? Is postfix up and running?

Comment: Other postfix logs are blank too. Postfix is running - going to check if it is up.

Comment: Update: Postfix is (and was) up to date.

Comment: `/etc/rsyslog.d/` is empty, there are no folders or files.

Comment: Which debian version are you using?

Comment: I'm running on 6.0.10.